# Let be $f(x)=(x+1)^2$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{x}-1$. Show that $f\circ g\neq g\circ f$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let be $f(x)=(x+1)^2$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{x}-1$. Show that $f\circ g\neq g\circ f$.

$f\circ g=f(g(x))=f(\sqrt{x}-1)=(\sqrt{x}-1+1)^2=(\sqrt{x})^2=x$

$g\circ f=g(f(x))=g((x+1)^2)=\sqrt{(x+1)^2}-1=x+1-1=x$

They are giving me equal. :'-(

How they are not equal?

Comment: Do you know the former definition of a function? It has several parts, and you have only checked one. Admittedly, this problem has explicitly hidden those parts from you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not entirely correct. As some have pointed out, it's partially a domain issue, however that's not the full picture. Indeed your step

$$\sqrt{(x+1)^2}-1=x+1-1$$

is **incorrect**. What you need to remember is that for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$,

$$\sqrt{a^2}=\lvert a\rvert.$$

This means that, while

$$(f\circ g)(x)=x,$$

we also have that

$$(g\circ f)(x)=\lvert x+1\rvert -1.$$

You should now be able to see that they are not equal. The reason this is the case, is because **$f$ is not invertible on $\mathbb{R}$**, as it is not injective. It is, however, invertible on $[-1,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,-1]$ separately, and indeed if we consider $f$ as a function $f:[-1,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$, as well as $g$ as a function $g:[0,\infty)\to[-1,\infty)$, then the above does reduce to $g$ being the inverse of $f$. However as we are not givens explicit domains for the functions, we assume their natural domains and codomains (this being their ranges), which give us $f:\mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty)$ and $g:[0,\infty)\to[-1,\infty)$. And it is precisely the fact that $f$ is considered on the entirety of $\mathbb{R}$ which makes it fail.

Comment: Though one might also say the implicit domain of the equation $f \circ g = g \circ f$ is $[0, \infty)$, in which case the claim is true! It's a strange question.

Comment: @aschepler the question is strange indeed, as it all depends on what domains you give the functions involved, which is not necessary an obvious choice

Comment: @Lorago thanks for your time. So $\sqrt{(x+1)^2}-1=\pm(x+1)-1$. We have $-(x+1)-1=-x-2$ when $x<-1$ and $+(x+1)-1=x$ when $x>-1$?

Comment: @bdvg2302 indeed, that is correct

Answer (score 4):

Notice that $g\circ f(-1)=-1$ while $f\circ g(-1)$ is undefined due to the negative under the square root, so they do not share the same domain. Hence they are different.

Comment: _Technically_, we don't know what the domains of $f$ and $g$ are. So we can't really argue about what domains $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ have. In my opinion that doesn't make this answer wrong, though. It makes the problem itself questionable. However, since the entire point of the problem is to remember that domains are a thing, I don't know how it could be done differently.